# calculate likelihood for each observation

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply Bayesian computation on a normal data with unknown mean and variance(sigma^2) using Gelman et.al approach. Which is :first draw sigma^2 then draw mean. I have done that and I have a list of mean and a list of sigma^2. Next step is to calculate the normal likelihood for each observation given the mean and variance that we sampled. I tried to write that in R but I receive a warning message that R can't find the mean (mu) and variance (sigma^2) .

I'm new at R any help will be appreciated.

```
likelihood <- function(y,mu,sigma2){
    
    singlelikelihoods = dnorm(y, mean = mu, sd = sigma2, log = T)
    sumall = sum(singlelikelihoods)
    return(sumall)   
}
```

update:
the data was derived from [this ODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173020/the-steady-state-of-the-odes-using-runsteady-not-correct) after that I add noise and this is part of my final data

```
[1,] 376146486
 [2,] 376149990
 [3,] 376153576
 [4,] 376157235
 [5,] 376160957
 [6,] 376164727
 [7,] 376168539
 [8,] 376172379
 [9,] 376176240
[10,] 376180117
[11,] 376183996
[12,] 376187877
[13,] 376191751
[14,] 376195612
[15,] 376199457
[16,] 376203286
[17,] 376207091
[18,] 376210873
[19,] 376214630
[20,] 376218357
[21,] 376222058
[22,] 376225728
[23,] 376229370
[24,] 376232980
[25,] 376236562
[26,] 376240114
[27,] 376243635
[28,] 376247127
[29,] 376250590
[30,] 376254025
[31,] 376257432
[32,] 376260812
[33,] 376264164
[34,] 376267491
[35,] 376270791
[36,] 376274066
[37,] 376277317
[38,] 376280541
[39,] 376283745
[40,] 376286923
```

Comment: you need to provide more information including an example data set and how you are passing the variables to the function.  it appears from your question that mu and sigma2 are not getting passed to the function successfully.

Comment: I derived my data from ODE (10000 observation) and then used the data to sample sigma2 and mu. Yes this is my problem the mu  and sigma2 are not getting passed to the function successfully?.

Comment: add a small version of your dataset as well as the  function call to your question

Comment: I want to help. So that is the dataset you are using.  Is it y in your function?  you are passing that and  two other  objects, mu and sigma2 into your function, correct?  How are those data object calculated?  So far I am guessing that they do not exist/are not being passed into the function, but I can't tell what is going on yet and I don't think I have all the pieces of your question in order to answer.  I would suggest you consider why your function is not finding all the variable - assuming that is the error message you are getting.